Error creating source: Internal Server Error: SQL
while I was setting up the source in Airbyte for my postgres database unable to do it beacause of internal server error :sql. I am attaching the error image here. although all test connections have been passed but it still not reading my postgres schema and its tables.
I want to sync PostgresSQL data with Airbyte(data extracting tool).For this I installed docker compose and airbyte in my system. when I try to set up the Source in Airbyte after filling up all the credentials it says all test connections have been passed but it's not proceed further to set the destination and giving the error of:-  Error creating source: Internal Server Error: SQL [select exists (select "public"."actor"."id", "public"."actor"."workspace_id", "public"."actor"."actor_definition_id", "public"."actor"."name", "public"."actor"."configuration", "public"."actor"."actor_type", "public"."actor"."tombstone", "public"."actor"."created_at", "public"."actor"."updated_at", "public"."actor"."default_version_id" from "public"."actor" where "public"."actor"."id" = cast(? as uuid))]; ERROR: column actor.default_version_id does not exist Position: 301   but I don't have any public schema in my database.

From a programming point of view the solution is simple: remove the column that the error message is complaining about from your query. However, the query seems to be generated by a tool. So, please ask the tool's product support why it detects a column that does not exists in the database
